# Get editText value from seekBar's progressChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, seekbar

help me please!
I have 3 seek Bars and 3 Edit Texts.
I just need value from each of edit text based on seek bar's progress Changed.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    int nil,nil1,nil2,nil3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //sb1 for seekBar1 ... etc
        //ed1 for editText1 ... etc

        sbValue(sb1, ed1);
        nil1 = nil; // I think I failed to get value in here
        sbValue(sb2, ed2);
        nil2 = nil;
        sbValue(sb3, ed3);
        nil3 = nil;

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d("","nil1 = "+nil1+"nil2 = "+nil2+"nil3 = "+nil3);
            }
        });
    }
```

and it is sbValue Methode

```
    public int sbValue(final SeekBar sb, final EditText ed) {
        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            ...
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                int val = sb.getProgress();
                ed.setText(String.valueOf(val));
                nil = val; //here is okay, the value is right.
            }
        });
        //but when I tried to get Log from here, It always give me 0.
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I changed my variable for nil as an array:

```
int[] nil = new int[3];
```

Then added a parameter for describing edittext.

```
sbValue(sb1, ed1, 1);
sbValue(sb2, ed2, 2);
sbValue(sb3, ed3, 3);
```

And the method is like this:

```
public int sbValue(final SeekBar sb, final EditText ed, final int sbSelect) {
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            int val = sb.getProgress();
            ed.setText(String.valueOf(val));
            switch (sbSelect){
                case 1: nil[0] = val; break;
                case 2: nil[1] = val; break;
                case 3: nil[2] = val; break;
            }
        }
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the progress status and you want to do something with that.

You are checking the Progress status inside the onProgressChanged method. So you know that you can only get the progress inside the onProgressChanged then how can you expect the progress status or value at outside the method.

Whatever you want to achieve, you should achieve inside the method

Comment: does variable "nil" cant catch the value of val after i call it outside of the method?

Comment: @Alca you can't get. Whatever you want to achieve, you should achieve inside the method